# iOS: Why is my subview appearing with a big spacing inside scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a single scrollview in my view controller and several subviews (textfields and labels). These subviews appear grouped in the middle of the screen, although I added constraints.

How can I make them appear with the standard spacing to the navigationbar?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried placing these subviews inside a subview which is the size of your scrollview's content? I've had similar problems, and that always did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a problem with translucent nav bar.

Turn on the nav bar translucent and see if the views are correctly positioned. If they are, you have to adjust the spacing in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout doesn't work the same way as everywhere else when inside a scrollview--it's a whole new ballgame (as described in apple's documentation).

If you place a UIView within the UIScrollView, and make sure you have that view the same size as the scrollview's content, you can use autolayout in this new view to place all your textfields/labels however you like.

For more info, see apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) on scrollviews & autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

setting

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

or, alternatively and corresponding in the storyboard, did fix it for iOS7. Don't know if this works for iOS 6